# Como dar el formato correcto a fechas en Power BI

Tags: date, formato, powerbi

Estoy realizando la conexión a un procedimiento almacenado en SQLServer, desde el origen de datos la columna `AnioMes` llega de la siguiente manera, donde 2021 corresponde al año y el ultimo par de dígitos corresponde al mes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez cargado en PowerBI tiene el mismo formato de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera dar el formato correcto separando el año y el mes en nuevas columnas, alguien puede darme una orientación en como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que crear dos columnas nuevas a partir de "AnioMes". Lo mejor es hacerlo desde la parte de la importación, es decir, desde Power Query. Para ello te vas a la opción del inicio "Transformar datos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez dentro, vas a la sección "Agregar columna", "Columna personalizada"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En nombre de columna pones "Año" y en la fórmula pones

```
= Text.Start([AnioMes], 4)
```

Quedando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haces lo mismo para el mes (Agregar columna --> Columna Personalizada):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También será interesante que el "Año" y el "mes" estén como enteros, para ello transformas el tipo de datos de texto a número entero (haciendo click a la izquierda del nombre del campo donde "ABC 123").

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente, te vas al menú "Inicio" y haces click en "Cerrar y aplicar"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya tendrás disponibles estas dos columnas nuevas en tu modelo de Power BI.

Comment: Al momento de crear la columna personalizada e ingresar la formula, la columna nueva me genera el siguiente error: `Expression.Error: No se puede convertir el valor 202101 al tipo Text.
Detalles:
    Value=202101
    Type=[Type]`, alguna sugerencia para su solución ?

Comment: Antes de agregar las nuevas columnas, convierte la columna "AnioMes" a texto.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, clara y concisa